# Stack position not accurate

Tags: flutter, dart, stack

I want  to add red blinking dot on the container when it is tapped, but the dot position is not accurate.
How to fix?

**MyApp**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'blinking_dot.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  double posx;
  double posy;

  void onTapDown(BuildContext context, TapDownDetails details) {
    print('${details.globalPosition}');
    final RenderBox box = context.findRenderObject();
    final Offset localOffset = box.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);
    setState(() {
      posx = localOffset.dx;
      posy = localOffset.dy;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: GestureDetector(
            onTapDown: (TapDownDetails details) => onTapDown(context, details),
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  height: double.infinity,width: double.infinity,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: Image.asset("assets/img.jpg")),
                Positioned(
                  child: BlinkingDot(),
                  left: posx,
                  top: posy,
                )
              ],
            )));
  }
}
```

**blinking_dot.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BlinkingDot extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BlinkingDotState createState() => _BlinkingDotState();
}

class _BlinkingDotState extends State<BlinkingDot>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _animationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _animationController =
        new AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 1));
    _animationController.repeat();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FadeTransition(
        opacity: _animationController,
        child: Container(
            height: 15,
            width: 15,
            child: FloatingActionButton(
              backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
            )));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
posy = localOffset.dy- MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top - kToolbarHeight;
```

also you need to decrease offset by half of the red dot size
in your case if will something like this

```
  posx = localOffset.dx - 7.5;
  posy = localOffset.dy- MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top - kToolbarHeight - 7.5;
```

Comment: why not? `padding.top` is height of status bar and `kToolbarHeight` is a height of AppBar it's constant, I test it on android emulator and iPhone XS simulator

Comment: please help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60568203/stack-position-inaccurate-when-scroll

Answer (score 1):

It's because you did not consider the following

1. You need to subtract AppBar height from dy.
2. You need to subtract the circle radius from both dx and dy.
3. You need to subtract the top padding from dy and left padding from
   dx.

**Do the following to get the expected result**

```
      posx = localOffset.dx - MediaQuery.of(context).padding.left - circleRadius;
      posy = localOffset.dy -MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top - circleRadius - kToolbarHeight;
```

Here is the complete snippet

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  //int _counter = 0;
  double posx;
  double posy;
  final circleRadius = 7.5;

  void onTapDown(BuildContext context, TapDownDetails details) {
    print('${details.globalPosition}');
    final RenderBox box = context.findRenderObject();
    final Offset localOffset = box.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);
    setState(() {
      posx =
          localOffset.dx - MediaQuery.of(context).padding.left - circleRadius;
      posy = localOffset.dy -MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top - circleRadius - kToolbarHeight;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: GestureDetector(
            onTapDown: (TapDownDetails details) => onTapDown(context, details),
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                    height: double.infinity,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: Image.asset("assets/img.jpg")),
                Positioned(
                  child: BlinkingDot(circleRadius: circleRadius),
                  left: posx,
                  top: posy,
                )
              ],
            )));
  }
}

class BlinkingDot extends StatefulWidget {
  final double circleRadius;

  const BlinkingDot({Key key, this.circleRadius}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _BlinkingDotState createState() => _BlinkingDotState();
}

class _BlinkingDotState extends State<BlinkingDot>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _animationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _animationController =
        new AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 1));
    _animationController.repeat();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FadeTransition(
        opacity: _animationController,
        child: Container(
            height: widget.circleRadius * 2,
            width: widget.circleRadius * 2,
            child: FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
            )));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

See the live demo [here](https://dartpad.dev/54cf71f4b54950c1bd18e2a7b1c9ce90).

Comment: so how should I fix?

Comment: subtract the appbar height.

Comment: thanks, the distance shorten now, but still slightly inaccurate.

Comment: try posy = localOffset.dy - AppBar().preferredSize.height

Comment: It works now, but I prefer Eugene answer. Thanks anyway

Comment: please help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60568203/stack-position-inaccurate-when-scroll

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking like this?

Home page

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  double posx;
  double posy;

  void onTapDown(BuildContext context, TapDownDetails details) {
    print('${details.globalPosition}');
    final RenderBox box = context.findRenderObject();
    final Offset localOffset = box.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);
    setState(() {
      posx = localOffset.dx;
      posy = localOffset.dy-70.0;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("widget.title"),
        ),
        body: GestureDetector(
          onTapDown: (TapDownDetails details) => onTapDown(context, details),
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                  height: double.infinity,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: Image.asset("assets/img.jpg")),
              Positioned(
                child: BlinkingDot(),
                left: posx,
                top: posy,
              )
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

BlinkingDot page

```
class BlinkingDot extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BlinkingDotState createState() => _BlinkingDotState();
}

class _BlinkingDotState extends State<BlinkingDot>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _animationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _animationController =
        new AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 1));
    _animationController.repeat();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FadeTransition(
        opacity: _animationController,
        child: Container(
            height: 15,
            width: 15,
            child: FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
            )));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: this still not very accurate bro

Comment: please help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60568203/stack-position-inaccurate-when-scroll